Error Pod install on flutter (Cocoapods, macOS Sequoia 15.1.1)
When running pod install in ios directory it shows error.

MacOS: Sequoia(15.1.1)
Xcode 16.1
Flutter doctor response


Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '11.4.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '11.4.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.4.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
Command
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/bin/pod install

Report

What did you do?

What did you expect to happen?

What happened instead?


Stack
   CocoaPods : 1.16.2
        Ruby : ruby 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 revision ef084cc8f4) [x86_64-darwin23]
    RubyGems : 3.5.18
        Host : macOS 15.1.1 (24B91)
       Xcode : 16.1 (16B40)
         Git : git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)
Ruby lib dir : /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

Plugins
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

Error
JSON::ParserError - Failed to parse JSON at file: '/Users/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.68.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json'.

unexpected token at '"src/core/channelz/channel_trace'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:66:in `rescue in from_json'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:759:in `from_string'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:733:in `from_file'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:188:in `specification'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:58:in `block in specification_name'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:217:in `search'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.16.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79076788/14071053

I have tried this solution but the error is same. I think there's something wrong with the macos latest update.

No, my mac version is same as yours. So, nothing is wrong with that.

The problem is that I am using cloud_firestore in the project and when pod is installing it shows an error "The plugin "cloud_firestore" requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version than your application is targeting." and when I updated the  platform :ios, '12.0' to platform :ios, '13.0' it displays the error I mentioned in the question.
